# removeLiqudityWithPermit: Invalid Signature

Tags: solidity, python, pancakeswap, ecrecover

So, I am trying to remove liquidity from a pancake v2 pair and I do not understand why this is not working. I am looking at the code, and I've triple checked every value, I don' think I am doing anything wrong. I need some help.

Here is my code:

```
    def to_32byte_hex(self, val):
        return to_hex(to_bytes(val).rjust(32, b'\0'))


    def build_remove_with_permit(self, token_address: ChecksumAddress):
    """
    :param token_address: liquidity pair token
    :return: raw transaction dict
    """
    # returns the correct values, confirmed because this 
    # function works on other pairs where I can call removeLiqudi
    token1, token2, liquidity_balance, minOutToken0, minOutToken1 = self.get_liq_remove_info(token_address)
    lp_contract = w3.eth.contract(token_address, abi=UNIV2_LP_ABI)
    max_fee_per_priority, max_fee_per_gas, xx = gas_estimator(w3, self.account.address, self.account.address, 0,
                                                              'low')
    # pancakeswap v2 is a uniswap v2 fork
    router_contract = w3.eth.contract(self.router, abi=UNIV2_ABI)
    # Prepare parameters
    # Getting these values directly from the pair contract ... 
    PERMIT_TYPEHASH = lp_contract.functions.PERMIT_TYPEHASH().call()
    DOMAIN_SEPARATOR = lp_contract.functions.DOMAIN_SEPARATOR().call()
    x19 = '\x19\x01'  # and this is also right from the contract source
  
    owner = self.account.address  # caller is me
    spender = self.router  # spender is router 
    value = liquidity_balance  # amount of liq tokens to burn
    nonce = lp_contract.functions.nonces(self.account.address).call()  # my nonce on the contract
    deadline = int(time.time() + 300)  # 5 minutes from now

    # Encode and hash the parameters
    x = eth_abi.encode(['bytes32', 'address', 'address', 'uint256', 'uint256', 'uint256'],
                            [PERMIT_TYPEHASH, to_checksum_address(owner), to_checksum_address(spender), value, nonce, deadline])
    # print(x)
    y = w3.solidity_keccak(['string', 'bytes32', 'bytes32'], [x19, DOMAIN_SEPARATOR, x])
    # print(y)
    signature = w3.eth.account.signHash(y, private_key=self.account.key)
    v, r, s = signature.v, self.to_32byte_hex(signature.r), self.to_32byte_hex(signature.s)
    # print(v,r,s)
    # Here I am just calling `permit` on the pair, to test whether or not I got it 
    # right, which for some reason, I have not!
    try:
        lp_contract.functions.permit(self.account.address, self.router, liquidity_balance, deadline, v, r, s).call(
            {'from': self.account.address})
    except ContractLogicError as err:
        print('[!] Contract reverted with: %s' % err)
        return {}


    raw_txn = {
        "from": self.account.address,
        "gas": 300000,  # 200000
        'maxPriorityFeePerGas': to_wei(max_fee_per_priority, 'gwei'),
        'maxFeePerGas': to_wei(max_fee_per_gas, 'gwei'),
        "to": self.router,
        "value": 0,
        "data": router_contract.encodeABI('removeLiquidityWithPermit',
                                          args=(to_checksum_address(token1), to_checksum_address(token2),
                                                liquidity_balance, minOutToken0, minOutToken1,
                                                self.account.address, deadline, True, v, r, s)),
        "nonce": w3.eth.get_transaction_count(self.account.address),
        "chainId": w3.eth.chain_id
    }
    return raw_txn
```

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with my code? As far as I can tell, I am doing this correctly.

I figure that if I can successfully call permit() on the pair contract, I should be able to then call removeLiquidityWithPermit(). So, in the code I shared, I am testing that with `call()`. This is the `permit` function on the LP pair contract:

```
function permit(address owner, address spender, uint value, uint deadline, uint8 v, bytes32 r, bytes32 s) external {
        require(deadline >= block.timestamp, 'Pancake: EXPIRED');
        bytes32 digest = keccak256(
            abi.encodePacked(
                '\x19\x01',
                DOMAIN_SEPARATOR,
                keccak256(abi.encode(PERMIT_TYPEHASH, owner, spender, value, nonces[owner]++, deadline))
            )
        );
        address recoveredAddress = ecrecover(digest, v, r, s);
        require(recoveredAddress != address(0) && recoveredAddress == owner, 'Pancake: INVALID_SIGNATURE');
        _approve(owner, spender, value);
         }
```

I am getting:

[!] Contract reverted with: execution reverted: Pancake: INVALID_SIGNATURE

Can anyone tell me why? Maybe I am missing something? Thanks ...

Comment: If I were you to debug this I would create a test solidity view function to just return the digest and compare with your `y` in python. It clearly says the signature is wrong, likely the digest computation is wrong